# How to delete files smaller than x kb with powershell script

Tags: powershell

Hello everyone I have 1 folder and include many sub folders and many `.txt` files.I want to delete `.txt` files especially smaller than 10`kb`.

I've tried this one but I got some errors every time.

```
$Dir  = "C:\Users\*************\Desktop\test"
'$SizeMin' = 10 #KB

Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Recurse | 
    Where {$_.Length / 10KB -lt $SizeMin} | 
        Remove-Item -Force
```

> "Unexpected token '$SizeMin' in expression or statement.
>           + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken"

Comment: you have TWO errors in your code. [*grin*] ///// [1] the one that is _probably_ causing the error you list is the single quotes around the definition of `$SizeMin` - that makes it a STRING instead of a variable. remove the quotes and that part will work. ///// [2] you are dividing by `10KB` ... and that gives you `10KB` chunks ... but you actually want `1KB` chunks. [*grin*] change the `10KB` to `1KB` and you will get that part working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever learning something new, especially coding, I find it best to break everything down and take my time writing drawn out code first and compacting it later. You could use and edit the following drawn out code to get a better understanding as to what is happening:

```
#Root directory
$dir = "C:\Users\*************\Desktop\test"

#Minimum size for file
$minSize = 10

#Throwing through every item in root directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | ForEach-Object{

    #Check if file length if less than 10
    if ($_.Length / 10KB -lt $minSize){
        Remove-Item $_ -Force
    }else{
        #File is too big to remove
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and all kind advices.İt's worked.

Comment: @BatuhanOzoguz Your welcome :) Please upvote and mark the appropriate response as answering your question

Comment: I tried this, but it ended up deleting EVERY file, regardless of size?

Comment: @LarryCai Not used SO in a while - sounds like you should raise a new question and include every detail you can think of. Most likely, there was a typo in your script.

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you, it removes files smaller than 10kb (10000 bytes) in a given directory:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\*************\Desktop\test'
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.stat -recurse |?{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.length -lt 10000}|?{Remove-Item $_.fullname -WhatIf}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helps code is working but files not deleting.

Comment: @BatuhanOzoguz Remove the `-whatif` to make sure the code removes the files you want.

Comment: I remove it.But still same

Comment: Change `?{Remove-Item` into `ForEach-Object { Remove-Item`. Better use the full cmdlet names instead of their aliases to prevent errors like this. `? ==> Where-Object` and `% ==> ForEach-Object`. Also, don't try and force everything into one line.

Comment: Thanks @Theo ! Edit the answer if that's going to help him!!

Comment: Ehhhhhh. Nope. It is not my answer, so I think it's better you edit it yourself.

Comment: @Theo this is all about contribution to help each other!

Comment: ..and that is exactly why I posted the **comment** instead of editing your code.