# Assistance creating a PowerShell script that Checks if a Specific Document is a certain size, if it is not it is then deleted

Tags: powershell, size

Community, I am needing assistance creating a PowerShell script that scans a folder directory for a specific file and confirms if its size is smaller than 4000KB. If it is then delete the file. If it is not then do nothing.

File name → test.xml
File location → C:\users\me\my stuff\Documents\test.xml

I was able to search other forums that search for all files below a size which is not my case ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528056/how-to-delete-files-smaller-than-x-kb-with-powershell-script)) this did help me piece together the following which does delete my file each time regardless of size. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you!

---

I tried the following script below, and expected it to remove my file if it was smaller than 4000 KB, it is deleting my file each time even if the size is larger than 4000 KB

```
$testfile = "C:\users\me\my stuff\Documents\test.xml"

#Minimum size for file
$minSize = 4000000

#searching for file with file size
Write-Host((Get-Item $testfile).length/1KB)
 #Check if file length if less than 4KB if not then delete it
    if ($_.Length / 1000 -lt $minSize){
       Remove-Item $testfile -Force    
    }
```

Comment: `$_` is the representation of the current item in the pipeline in which you have none. Get the actual file length like you're doing so in your `Write-Host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this, it sets the size of your file in a variable and if that value is below your minSize it will delete the file:

```
# File to check
$testfile = "C:\users\me\my stuff\Documents\test.xml"

# Minimum size for file in KB
$minSize = 4000

# Get the filesize
$size = ((Get-Item $testfile).length/1KB)

# Remove the file if it's smaller than $minSize
if ($size -lt $minSize){
   Remove-Item $testfile -Force
}
```

Comment: this worked for me. I had spent hours trying to figure it out before asking for help. Much appreciated and thank you for your time and wisdom 